# How to regularly expire or delete docker build cache?

Tags: r, docker, gitlab-ci

Is there a way to expire the cache of the docker build command without explicitly adding the `--no-cache` flag?

Let's say I would like to search for package (security) updates at least once per week when building my image in the gitlab ci-cd pipeline. And the rest of the time allow caching to speed up the build.

I was thinking of using an auxiliary artifact that expires after certain time, but this is probably not the most elegant (and certainly not portable) solution.

Example of my docker file:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.0:

# Apply OS updates
# This will be by default cached
RUN apt-get update && apt-get --yes upgrade

COPY myscript.R ./myscript.R

CMD [ "Rscript", "./myscript.R" ]
```

Comment: If you `docker build --pull`, it will contact the registry on every build and pull down a new base image if there is a change, but be fairly quick otherwise when there isn't.  If your only concern is around security updates in the base image then `docker pull` is enough: if the `FROM` image has changed then none of the subsequent caching will have an effect.

Comment: Thank you @DavidMaze . That would work for the projects that use up to date images. Old images/versions do not update the security patches that frequently. I use `RUN apt update && apt upgrade`, which is most of the time cached